# Remove last three characters from all filenames in a directory

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a directory with about 10 files and I want to remove the last three characters from the names of all of these files. Anyone know a terminal command that can do this?

And separately, how would I change the characters in the names of all these files to lowercase?

Comment: These are two different questions, you should separate them into two different posts.

Comment: Removing the characters from files is very  different from removing them from  file names.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `rename`. Install it with:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

Remove last three characters from all filenames in current directory:

```
rename 's/...$//' *
```

Change the characters in the names of all files from current directory to lowercase:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

For more info see `man rename`.

Comment: Great cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last 3 characters:

```
for i in *
do
j=`echo $i | sed -e 's/...$//'`
mv $i $j
done
```

Change names to lower case:

```
for i in *
do
j=`echo $i | tr A-Z a-z`
mv $i $j
done
```

Comment: is it bash programming??

Comment: Will work in bash or sh, most shells I think (but not csh, which has a different syntax).

Comment: You should be able to open a terminal and just enter the given strings at the command prompt.

Comment: what exactly you call it as, loops in terminal or what , I dont know anything , will search on google all about it , just want a "term" to google related to this kind of statements.

Comment: `man bash` will tell you what you need to know, but if you need to Google it, search for `bash for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can use [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

**Single line**

```
for filename in *; do newname=${filename:0:-3}; newname=${newname,,}; mv "$filename" "$newname"; done
```

**Multiple lines with comments**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop through all files in the directory
for filename in *; do

    # Remove the last three characters from the name
    newname=${filename:0:-3}

    # Convert to lowercase
    newname=${newname,,}

    # Rename the file by moving it
    mv "$filename" "$newname"

done
```